custom tailwind color doesn't apply in css
I want to add some custom color to tailwind and use them in the css.
here is my tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode:'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      color: {
          primary: "#FF69b4", 
          secondary: "#333333",
          brand: "#243c5a",
          primary: {
            50:"245 243 255",
            100: "237 233 254",
            200: "221 214 254",
            300: '196 181 253', 
            400: '167 139 250',
            500: "139 92 246",
            600: "124 58 237",
            700: "109 40 217",
            800: "91 33 182",
            900: "46 16 101",
          },
          muted: {
            50:"248 250 252",
            100: "241 245 249",
            200: "226 232 240",
            300: '203 213 225', 
            400: '148 163 184',
            500: "100 116 139",
            600: "71 85 105",
            700: "51 65 85",
            800: "30 41 59",
            900: "15 23 42",
          }
      }
    },

but I find my css don't work, for example
.nni-checkbox .nni-checkbox-label-text {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: rgb(var(--color-muted-400)/1);
   color: rgb(var(--color-muted-400)/var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

--color-muted-400 is not found as shown

<span  class="text-muted-400">Frontend Developer</span>

where text-muted-400 is also not found in styles.
anything wrong I did in the tailwind.config.js

First its colors not color and AFAIK it should be under theme or theme.extend in the config file. Secondly, you need to use the theme function in the CSS file. You can't just directly refer to the tailwind color using CSS variable like that.

Does this answer your question? Can tailwind colors be referenced from CSS?

You have a couple of issues.

You're extending color. You'll instead want to extend colors.
You have a duplicate key in your colors primary. Please use one or the other but not both.
You're declaring the colors incorrectly. It looks like you want rgb but currently they are numbers with spaces in between.

Try this config:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        secondary: '#333333',
        brand: '#243c5a',
        primary: {
          50: 'rgb(245, 243, 255)',
          100: 'rgb(237, 233, 254)',
          200: 'rgb(221, 214, 254)',
          300: 'rgb(196, 181, 253)',
          400: 'rgb(167, 139, 250)',
          500: 'rgb(139, 92, 246)',
          600: 'rgb(124, 58, 237)',
          700: 'rgb(109, 40, 217)',
          800: 'rgb(91, 33, 182)',
          900: 'rgb(46, 16, 101)',
        },
        muted: {
          50: 'rgb(248, 250, 252)',
          100: 'rgb(241, 245, 249)',
          200: 'rgb(226, 232, 240)',
          300: 'rgb(203, 213, 225)',
          400: 'rgb(148, 163, 184)',
          500: 'rgb(100, 116, 139)',
          600: 'rgb(71, 85, 105)',
          700: 'rgb(51, 65, 85)',
          800: 'rgb(30, 41, 59)',
          900: 'rgb(15, 23, 42)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

https://play.tailwindcss.com/PKiIHNA0As
